# If TransactionProxyFactoryBean is used for service layer bean then is there any need of transaction annotation driven in dao?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

The interface for service layer is :

```
EMS.java:

public interface EMS extends UserDetailsService {

    public void saveUser(User user);
}
```

and its implementation:

```
EMSImpl.java:

@Service("emsImpl")
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class EMSImpl implements EMS {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dao")
    private EMSDao dao;


    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        dao.saveUser();
    }
}
```

The interface for dao:

```
EMSDao.java:

public interface EMSDao {

    public void saveUser(User user);
}
```

And its implementation:

```
HibernateEMSDao.java

@Repository("EMSDao")
public class HibernateEMSDao extends HibernateDaoSupport implements EMSDao {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());  

    private SchemaHelper schemaHelper;

    public void setSchemaHelper(SchemaHelper schemaHelper) {
        this.schemaHelper = schemaHelper;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public synchronized void saveUser(final User user) {        
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.merge(user);
        }       

    private void storeUser(User user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
    }

    public void createSchema() {        
        try {
            getHibernateTemplate().find("from User user where user.id = 1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.warn("expected database schema does not exist, will create. Error is: " + e.getMessage());
            schemaHelper.createSchema();
            User admin = new User();
            admin.setUsername("admin");
            admin.setName("Admin");
            admin.setEmail("admin");
            admin.setPassword("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");
            admin.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(new Role("admin", "ADMINISTRATOR"))));
            logger.info("inserting default admin user into database");
            storeUser(admin);           
            logger.info("schema creation complete");                        
            return;
        }
        logger.info("database schema exists, normal startup");      
    }
}
```

The bean `ems` in `appliactionContext.xml` is created by `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`. Also I am using `<tx:annotation-driven />`

The complete applicationContext.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean class="info.ems.config.EMSConfigurer"/>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.acegisecurity.providers.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

    <bean id="ems" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>        
    <property name="target">            
        <bean class="info.ems.EMSImpl" init-method="init">
            <property name="dao" ref="dao"/>
            <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
            <property name="localeList" value="${ems.locales}"/>
            <property name="releaseVersion" value="${ems.version}"/>
            <property name="releaseTimestamp" value="${ems.timestamp}"/>
            <property name="emsHome" value="${ems.home}"/>
        </bean>
    </property>        
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>                
            <prop key="store*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="remove*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>                
            <prop key="bulkUpdate*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,readOnly</prop>
        </props>
    </property>        
    </bean>   

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="info.ems.datasource.DataSourceFactory">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database.validationQuery}"/>
    <property name="dataSourceJndiName" value="${database.datasource.jndiname}"/>
    </bean>     

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>        
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>        
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>    
        </props>
    </property>        
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="info.ems.hibernate.HibernateEMSDao" init-method="createSchema">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>        
    <property name="schemaHelper">
        <bean class="info.ems.hibernate.SchemaHelper">                                
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
            <property name="hibernateDialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>   
            <property name="dataSourceJndiName" value="${database.datasource.jndiname}"/>
        </bean>                
    </property>
    </bean>       
</beans>
```

I want to know:

- Is it the right configuration for handling database transaction by spring?
- Is it needed to use `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` along with `<tx:annotation-driven />`?

Any information or web-link where I can get example will be very helpful.

Thanks and regards.

Edit: after getting suggestion from [skaffman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21234/skaffman) the modified appliactionContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean class="info.ems.config.EMSConfigurer"/>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.acegisecurity.providers.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

    <bean id="ems" class="info.ems.EMSImpl" init-method="init">
            <property name="dao" ref="dao"/>
            <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
            <property name="localeList" value="${ems.locales}"/>
            <property name="releaseVersion" value="${ems.version}"/>
            <property name="releaseTimestamp" value="${ems.timestamp}"/>
            <property name="emsHome" value="${ems.home}"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="info.ems.datasource.DataSourceFactory">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${database.validationQuery}"/>
    <property name="dataSourceJndiName" value="${database.datasource.jndiname}"/>
    </bean>     

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>        
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>        
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</prop>    
        </props>
    </property>        
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="info.ems.hibernate.HibernateEMSDao" init-method="createSchema">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>        
    <property name="schemaHelper">
        <bean class="info.ems.hibernate.SchemaHelper">                                
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
            <property name="hibernateDialect" value="${hibernate.dialect}"/>   
            <property name="dataSourceJndiName" value="${database.datasource.jndiname}"/>
        </bean>                
    </property>
    </bean>       
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it the right configuration for handling database transaction by spring?

It's perfectly valid, but it's confusing and duplicates work. This will probably generate two layers of transactional proxies, although I doubt that will behave any differently.

As you say, you probably don't want to use both `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` and `<tx:annotation-driven />` at the same time.

Your `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` config is using externalised method name patterns to decide which methods get which transaction semantics.  This is fine, although with current versions of Spring it's usually easier to use annotations *instead* of the `transactionAttributes` property on `TransactionProxyFactoryBean`.

Given your config, I suggest getting rid of the explicit `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` bean definition (`<tx:annotation-driven />` will create its own one as required, behind the scenes). Replace that with the undecorated `EMSImpl`, and `<tx:annotation-driven />` will generate the transaction proxy automatically.

Comment: I have added modified appliactionContext.xml according to your suggestion and tested it, it's working. Is this what you are suggesting? I didn't made any change to other java code, i.e., EMS.java, EMSImpl.java, EMSDao.java, HibernateEMSDao.java.